How to assign a crs to a raster::stack object containing many raster layers with different environmental variables in R
I have a raster stack that contains mean sea surface temperature, mean sea surface salinity, and mean chlorophyll-a rasters that were derived from netcd4 files, and I have calculated the depth, slope, and the distance that the dolphins are from reefs using a GEBCO file.
I am trying to get the coordinates from the object 'coords_dolphin' from the environmental variables raster::stack 'env' but I am getting this warning message.
Warning message:
attribute variables are assumed to be spatially constant throughout all geometries  

I'm wondering if this is because all the raster layers in the raster stack object and the data points need to have the same crs of 4326.
I can't share my data due to ownership issues
#Make the dataframe a spatial object of class = "sf" with a CRS of 4326
coords_dolphins <- st_as_sf(x=MyDf, coords = c("Longitude_E", "Latitude_N"), crs = 4326)

#Stack the predictors into a raster stack object 
env <- stack(resampled_sss, resampled_sst, resampled_chla, depth, slope, distance)
plot(env)

#Rename the environmental predictors 
names(env) <-c("SSS", "SST", "Chlor-a", "Depth", "Slope", "Distance")

#Make sure the crs of the raster stack is the same as the coordinates
crs(env) <- crs('+init=EPSG:4326')

#take coords from coords_dolphin which are on environment
xy <- st_intersection(coords_dolphins, st_as_sfc(st_bbox(env)))

Output of xy:
Simple feature collection with 707 features and 33 fields
Geometry type: POINT
Dimension:     XY
Bounding box:  xmin: 33.69052 ymin: 27.15528 xmax: 33.98925 ymax: 27.85163
Geodetic CRS:  WGS 84


I think you append sf tag here. github search sf warning,  where it might be discussed [by Edzer] what spatially constant means under intersection. raster::stack, terra::c both assume same extent resolution which implies same crs, but crs by layer can be tested prior to terra::c. Do you expect chlorophyll-a to be spatially constant?

Under the circumstances, yes, I think that mean chlorophyll-a levels are very similar are very similar for the region. I wouldn't say constant, but similar as I created a mean raster from 14 years of chorophyll-a measurements

Then it's just a 'warning' that doesn't upend your assumptions.

The warning is coming from st_intersection() function, but I would treat it as a informative message, nothing to be worried about. Regarding CRS: it has to be the same for both intersected features, otherwise st_intersection() will throw an error. And I would consider to use terra::project() to reproject the rasters from one crs to another instead of <- assignment. Something as: env <- terra::project(env, coords_dolphins).

When asking a R question, please include a minimal, self-contained, reproducible example, that is use some example data that ships with R, or create some with code. It does not matter that you cannot share your data, there is no need for it.
